# How to specify table names in DatabaseLink for access database that have spaces in the names?

Tags: sql, databaselink

I am able to establish the connection with the access database as follows:

```
connection=OpenSQLConnection[
    JDBC[
        "Microsoft Access(UCanAccess)",
        file
    ]
]
```

Also can query the tables that have no spaces in them via:

```
SQLSelect[connection,"MyTable","ShowColumnHeadings"->True,"MaxRows"->10]//TableForm
```

But when the table name has spaces in them I try the following:

```
SQLSelect[connection,"[My Table]","ShowColumnHeadings"->True,"MaxRows"->10]//TableForm
```

And I get the following message:

> SQLTable::tablename: "[My Table]" is not a valid table name. A valid
> table name is a string with no spaces which may be wrapped in
> SQLTable.

Comment: just a simple question: have you tried to just use "My Table"? I would expect SQLSelect to do the necessary escaping...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Yes tried that as well. Doesn't work!